# Enhancing Inbound Call Detail Retrieval and Triggering App Activation on Call Display

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, caller-id

Currently, I require enhanced details regarding inbound calls through a third-party API.

While it is feasible to configure ["Open apps in browser for incoming PSTN calls"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-calling-policy) it only activates when you answer the call.

Is there a way to trigger this action as soon as the call appears on your screen?

It appears that the application at https://www.lyncwizard.com/products.html#TeamsWizard_Hotkey exhibited the desired behavior, but it is incompatible with the latest Teams version.

Comment: Is this working in Classic Teams for you?

Comment: "Open apps in browser for incoming PSTN calls" is working with classic teams